# Getting popuptemplate from feature layer to pop up when selecting row from table using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using esri javascript api 4.3 in an Angular 2 application.

I initially generate the map using this code:

```
OnInit() {
  this.map = new Map({
    basemap: 'streets'
  });

  this.map.layers.add(new FeatureLayer({
    url: 'http://test/rest/services/Project_map/MapServer/0', 
    id: '0',
    visible: true,
    outFields: ["*"],
    popupTemplate: this.jobsTemplate
  }));

  this.view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: this.map,
    center: new Point({
      x: -111.876,
      y: 40.758,
    }),
    zoom: 12,
    rotation: 0
  });
}
```

When a feature on the map is clicked I get a popup containing the values for that feature. That works fine.

There is also a table that has a row for each feature on the map.

When a table row is clicked, I execute the following code, passing into it the lat and long for that feature:

```
zoomToPoint(zoomLong: number, zoomLat: number) {
  this.view.center = new Point({x: zoomLong, y: zoomLat});
  this.view.zoom = 15;
  this.view.popup.open({location: this.view.center});
}
```

I get a popup at the correct location. But, the popup is empty.

I want it to use the popupTemplate assigned to the feature layer and containing the values for the feature at that location.

Just like what happens if I click on the feature.

Comment: I think [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/featurelayerview-query/index.html) example might be useful. Mainly you would want to click a feature, not a map point, by using query.

Comment: Thanks NettaB.  Yeah.  I had chased my tail for a while trying to follow that example.  It says to use "features: [result]" in the view.popup.open method.  But, it is not clear what "[result]" is supposed to be.

Comment: You can fiddle with their examples, using the [sandbox](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=featurelayerview-query) environment. For me it's the only way to understand their examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#open you have to either specify -along with the location- the title and content to the popup, or the features of the selected point.

```
this.view.popup.open({ location: this.view.center, title: 'foo', content: 'bar' });
```

or

```
this.view.popup.open({ location: this.view.center, features: [selectedGraphic]});
```

**Edit:** here is another shot, with a query to your feature layer, to select the features placed at the coordinates from your table

```
function qLayer(pt) {
  var query = layer.createQuery();
  query.geometry = pt;
  query.spatialRelationship = "intersects";
  return layer.queryFeatures(query);
}
function showPopup(res) {
  view.popup.open({
    features: res.features,
    updateLocationEnabled: true,
  });
}

zoomToPoint(zoomLong: number, zoomLat: number) {
  var point = new Point([zoomLong, zoomLat]);
  qLayer(point).then(showPopup);
  view.goTo({
    target: point,
    zoom: 15,
  });
}
```

here is a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/0tkx4091/17/ click on the filename, above the map

Comment: Thanks.  How do you get "[selectedGraphic]"?

Comment: i've edited my answer

Comment: Thanks.  I can see what is intended.  But, result array is always empty.

Comment: i've edited again my answer

Comment: The query works great.  The results being passed to "showPopup" do contain the correct feature and all the attributes are correct.  However, the popup still does not pop up.  The fiddle does exactly what I am trying to do.  But, I cannot find what is different.

Comment: maybe that means the method open() of view.popup is not found ? Inside showPopup function, can you put into console.log your view ? `console.log(view)`

Comment: console.log(view) will not show anything in the console.  However, when I do console.log(view) in the other functions the view looks good in the console log.

Comment: In zoomToPoint, view looks good in console.

Comment: In qLayer,  view looks good in console.

Comment: In showPopup, view does not show in console.  No error.  Just nothing there.

Comment: is `function showPopup()` in the same scope of `var view = new MapView()` ?

Comment: Yes showPopup() is in the same scope as  var view = new MapView();

Comment: My code is essentially the same as yours given above.  If var view is in scope for zoomToPoint() and for qLayer() then it should also be in scope for showPopup().  The difference is that showPopup() is fired off using ".then".  I don't know why that would change the scope of view.

Comment: did you write, inside showPopup() function, **this**.view.popup.open() ?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, everywhere you have "view" in your code, I have "this.view."  I am currently looking into using arrow functions.  Hoping that might provide some relief.

Comment: ok, instead of writing everywhere `this.view`, put it a var, then use that var, ie: `var t_view = this.view`. I made a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m1tdmjgv/

Comment: Two things.  First is that the scope problem was fixed by ".then(this.showPopup.bind(this));"  This kept the meaning for "this" inside of the showPopup function.  Second is that after that it was only showing the popup for the first feature.  Had to add query.where = "ProjectNumber = " + project; in order to identify the correct feature to show.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad you got it working, cheers